# error while generating signed apk init

Tags: java, android, android-studio, libgdx, apk

Hey i am trying to generate signed apk to upload to the store and i keep getting this error:

```
Error:FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':android:lintVitalRelease'.

  > Could not resolve all files for configuration ':android:lintClassPath'.
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.1.0
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.com-intellij:intellij-core:26.1.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.1.0/intellij-core-26.1.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/com-intellij/intellij-core/26.1.0/intellij-core-26.1.0.pom'. Received status code 500 from server: 
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.0.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-kotlin:26.1.0
  >        project :android > com.android.tools.lint:lint-gradle:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-checks:26.1.0 > com.android.tools.lint:lint-api:26.1.0
  >   Could not resolve com.android.tools.external.org-jetbrains:uast:26.1.0.
  >   Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.1.0/uast-26.1.0.pom'.
  >   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/external/org-jetbrains/uast/26.1.0/uast-26.1.0.pom'. Received status code 500 from server:
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 10s

I dont know what to do about it it never happend to me before

Comment: try Rebuilding or Cleaning the project, if that doesn't work, Invalidate Cache & Restart A.S

Answer (score 0):

***Try this***

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            lintOptions {
                disable 'MissingTranslation'
                checkReleaseBuilds false
                abortOnError false
            }
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Comment: gives me this error Error:(35, 0) Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.

Comment: Just put the "signingConfigs" block on top of "buildTypes" block in your build.gradle.

Answer (score 0):

**Enable embedded Maven repository** in the Android Studio settings, choose **File > Settings (Android Studio > Preferences** on Mac), select the **Gradle > Android Studio** category in the left pane, and tick Enable embedded Maven repository checkbox.

[image]

Refresh all your gradle project and build.